# slow download over socket

Tags: c#, sockets, networking, tcp, client-server

I've written a proprietary protocol (client and server) on top of TCP in C#, which sends files from client to server and vice versa.

Since it's full duplex in concept, the receiving and sending methods are the same for both client and server.

The protocol allows `client1` to upload a file to the `server`, and once the file is buffered (on the server), `client1` can decide whether `client2` and/or `client3` get the file. (the `server` can send the only to `client2`, only to `client3`, or to both simultaneously depending on the request by `client1`).

The problem is that I witness slow data transfer for server -> client, about 140 kb/s when the actual bandwidth is much higher for both the client, and obviously for the server as well.

At first I thought it was simply the max bandwidth for this specific connection (client at my home and server at a remote place), but then I saw that the transfer rate **doubles** when I open `client2` and `client3` on my PC and let the server send them both the file simultaneously; it remains the same for each client, but since they are both on the same PC, the total throughput on my local network doubled.

1. Any thoughts about where my problem can be? How can I increase the server -> client transfer rate to it's maximum?
2. Any general points of improvement regarding my code will be highly appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
struct ReceiveBuffer
{
    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 16;
    public byte[] BUFFER;
    public int ToReceive;
    public MemoryStream BufStream;

    public ReceiveBuffer(int toRec)
    {
        BUFFER = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
        ToReceive = toRec;
        BufStream = new MemoryStream(toRec);
    }
}

struct SendBuffer
{
    public const int BUFFER_SIZE = 1024 * 16;
    public byte[] BUFFER;
    public int sent;

    public SendBuffer(byte[] data)
    {
        BUFFER = new byte[data.Length];
        Buffer.BlockCopy(data, 0, BUFFER, 0, data.Length);
        sent = 0;
    }
}

public void ReceiveAsync()
{
    try
    {
        socket.BeginReceive(lenBuffer, 0, 4, SocketFlags.None,
                            receiveCallback, null);                
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
         //handle disconnection
    }

}

void receiveCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        if (rec == 0)
        {
            if (Disconnected != null)
            {
                Disconnected(this);
                return;
            }
        }

        if (rec != 4)
        {
            //less than 4 bytes received...error
            return;
        }

        receiveBuffer = new ReceiveBuffer(BitConverter.ToInt32(lenBuffer, 0));
        socket.BeginReceive(receiveBuffer.BUFFER, 0,
                            receiveBuffer.BUFFER.Length,
                            SocketFlags.None, receivePacketCallback, null);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        //raise disconnection event
    }
}

void receivePacketCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int rec = socket.EndReceive(ar);
        if (rec <= 0)
        {
            return;
        }
        receiveBuffer.BufStream.Write(receiveBuffer.BUFFER, 0, rec);
        receiveBuffer.ToReceive -= rec;
        if (receiveBuffer.ToReceive > 0)
        {
            Array.Clear(receiveBuffer.BUFFER, 0, receiveBuffer.BUFFER.Length);
            socket.BeginReceive(receiveBuffer.BUFFER, 0,
                                receiveBuffer.BUFFER.Length,
                                SocketFlags.None, receivePacketCallback, null);
            return;
        }

        if (DataReceived != null)
        {
            //raise dataReceived event
        }
        receiveBuffer.Dispose();
        if (socket !=null)
            ReceiveAsync();

    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        //handle disconnection
    }

}

// Send Async
public void SendAsyncString(string str, CommandsToClient cmd)
{
    BinaryWriter bw = new BinaryWriter(new MemoryStream());
    bw.Write((int)cmd);
    bw.Write((int)str.Length);
    bw.Write(Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str));
    bw.Close();
    byte[] data = ((MemoryStream)(bw.BaseStream)).ToArray();
    bw.BaseStream.Dispose();
    SendAsync(data);
}

public void SendAsync(byte[] data)
{
    int toSend;
    byte[] dataWithHeader = Combine(BitConverter.GetBytes(data.Length), data);
    sendBuffer = new SendBuffer(dataWithHeader);
    if (sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent > SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE)
        toSend = SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE;
    else
        toSend = sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent;
    socket.BeginSend(sendBuffer.BUFFER, 0,toSend, SocketFlags.None,
                     sendCallback, null);
}

void sendCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    try
    {
        int bytesSent = socket.EndSend(ar);
        if (bytesSent == 0)
        {
            //raise disconnection event
        }
        sendBuffer.sent += bytesSent;
        if (sendBuffer.sent==sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length)
        {
            sendBuffer.Dispose();
            return;
        }
        int toSend;
        if (sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent > SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE)
            toSend = SendBuffer.BUFFER_SIZE;
        else
            toSend = sendBuffer.BUFFER.Length - sendBuffer.sent; 

        socket.BeginSend(sendBuffer.BUFFER, sendBuffer.sent,toSend,
                        SocketFlags.None, sendCallback, null);
    }
    catch (SocketException se)
    {
        //hande disconnection
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you sure to want to write your own proprietary protocol? Can't you use existing things?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch, Yes. I haven't found a protocol that suits my needs.

Comment: All this can be done with several existing protocols.

Comment: @Daniel - Heyup. I've had a look through your code and can't see any glaring issues. I think what Basile might mean is have you considered using a network library?

Comment: @MarcF thanks for the answer Marc. I don't see why I shouldn't write my own protocol on top of TCP. From all of the protocols I've seen, no one gives me what I truly need. 
In any case the problem seems to be the buffer sizes. I'll answer it properly for other people...

Comment: @Daniel - What exactly do you need the protocol to do / be good at?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that what was slowing me down was the buffer sizes.

On my PC:
I can upload @ about 50 KBytes/sec
I can download @ about 600 KBytes/sec 
(these values obviously change, depending on the remote host, however it does give a good estimate)

On the server:
upload and download much higher bandwidth (tens of  Mega Bytes)

Here's the settings I'm now using which allow me a high transfer rate:

on client side (my PC)

```
Receive Buffer = 128 Kbytes
Send    Buffer = 32  Kbytes
```

on server side:

```
Receive Buffer =  64 Kbytes
Send    Buffer =  256 Kbytes
```